# ubuntu 12.04 - svn relocated and system restart

Tags: svn, ubuntu-12.04

I think my server has been hacked but I cannot be sure.

I had installed and got running svn on ubuntu 12.04. After installing I got one machine to checkout the repository on username joe. Last night I checked out the repository on my own machine on username john. But suddenly today I get this message when trying to commit:

'ERROR Repository moved temporarily to 'http://www.mydomain.com'; please relocate'

I don't know where to start looking here, some search results indicate it might be a hook script, other say sloppy config files.

I have svn installed with webDAV. The config file is:
/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf:

```
<Location /backuprepos/filesystem>
DAV svn
SVNPath /home/backuprepos/filesystem
AuthType Basic
AuthName "filesystem subversion repository"
AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
Require valid-user
</Location>
```

The passwords I added to the following file:

```
htpasswd -c /etc/subversion/passwd user_name
```

Really need to some help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At long last I found the answer to my problem.

We had a htaccess blanket rule for all 404's which redirected to the index

SVN apparently uses 404 (not found) errors in order to add new resources. Thus the 404 redirected the svn to the rootYou must allow this one to pass through instead of making a redirection, or svn will get confused.